# Current location Detail Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I have implemented an app that shows me the current location on Map. I have the coordinates of my location. We got Places api web services, but it is of version 11.2.0 and my project has version of 10.2.0 gms service.
How do I do that so that I can have address of my Location?

I have implemented a function but that does not seem to have any effect.

```
void getPlaceDetail() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
                .getCurrentPlace(googleApiClient, null);

        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer placeLikelihoods) {

                for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : placeLikelihoods) {
                    et.setText(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAddress());
                }

                placeLikelihoods.release();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem.

```
void getPlaceDetail(LatLng currLatLng) {
    Geocoder geocoder= new Geocoder(getActivity());
    try {
        if(currLatLng == null ) return;
        List<Address> address= geocoder.getFromLocation(currLatLng.latitude, currLatLng.longitude, 1);
        et.setText(address.get(0).getAddressLine(0) +" "+ address.get(0).getAddressLine(1));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```